# Moodle - Criando Temas

Tags: php, moodle, temas

Oi, estou criando um tema para Moodle e não consigo instala-lo nem fazer testes, o tema tem somente 3 arquivos e o .css está em branco, só para fazer testes...

**arquivo config.php (fica na raiz do tema que tem o nome de temaTeste, então fica temaTeste/config.php)**

```
<?php

$THEME->name = 'base';
$THEME->doctype = 'html5';

$THEME->parents = array();

$THEME->sheets = array('base');

$THEME->layouts = array(
    // Most backwards compatible layout without the blocks - this is the layout used by default
    'base' => array(
        'file' => 'standard.php',
        'regions' => array(),
    ),
);



$THEME->javascripts = array();
$THEME->javascripts_footer = array();


?>
```

**arquivo standard.php (temaTeste/layout/standard.php)**

```
<?php
$hassidepre = $PAGE->blocks->region_has_content('side-pre', $OUTPUT);
$hassidepost = $PAGE->blocks->region_has_content('side-post', $OUTPUT);
echo $OUTPUT->doctype(); ?>
<html <?php echo $OUTPUT->htmlattributes() ?>>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $PAGE->title ?></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $OUTPUT->pix_url('favicon', 'theme')?>" />

    <?php echo $OUTPUT->standard_head_html() ?>
</head>

<body id="<?php p($PAGE->bodyid); ?>" class="<?php p($PAGE->bodyclasses); ?>">

<?php echo $OUTPUT->standard_top_of_body_html() ?>

<table id="page">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <h1 class="headermain"><?php echo $PAGE->heading ?></h1>
            <div class="headermenu"><?php echo $OUTPUT->login_info(); echo $PAGE->headingmenu; ?></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $OUTPUT->blocks_for_region('side-pre') ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo core_renderer::MAIN_CONTENT_TOKEN ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $OUTPUT->blocks_for_region('side-post') ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <p class="helplink"><?php echo page_doc_link(get_string('moodledocslink')) ?></p>
            <?php
            echo $OUTPUT->login_info();
            echo $OUTPUT->home_link();
            echo $OUTPUT->standard_footer_html();
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<?php echo $OUTPUT->standard_end_of_body_html() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Eu preciso intala-lo no moodle e ele precisa rodar, é um tema simples apenas para estudo/teste.

Comment: A documentação diz alguma coisa sobre onde esses arquivos devem ficar? ou como é feito o carregamento deles?

Comment: cara, a documentação está muito confusa e não consegui entender como usar os blocks hardcoded, preciso de exemplos e não achei lá!

Answer (score 2):

Abaixo um breve passo a passo de como criar um thema básico para o moodle na versão 2.0 em diante.

**Passo a passo:**

1. Faça download do pacote de instalação do moodle http://moodle.org;
2. Faça a extração dos arquivos;
3. Navegue até o diretório `/theme/clean`, em seguida copie todo seu conteúdo e cole no diretório `/theme/seu_diretorio_do_tema_moodle`. 
   Para o propósito desse passo a passo chamarei o tema de `cleantheme`. De preferência, utilize sempre letra minúscula.
4. Ao abrir o diretório `cleantheme` você encontrará diversos arquivos e diretórios. Esses são:

> `config.php` - Onde todas as configurações de tema são feitas.
>   (*Contém alguns elementos que exigem alteração de nome*).
>
> `lib.php` - Onde todas as funções para as configurações de temas são
>   encontrados. (*Contém alguns elementos que exigem alteração de nome*);
>
> `settings.php`- Onde toda a configuração para este tema são criados.
>   (*Contém alguns elementos que exigem mudança de nome*);
>
> `version.php` - Onde o número da versão e as informações do
>   componente tipo tema são mantidos. (*Contém alguns elementos que
>   exigem mudança de nome*);
>
> `/lang/` - Esta pasta contém todos os subdiretórios de idiomas, nele
>   poderá adicionar as traduções para seu tema. Ex: diretório
>   `pt_br/theme_cleantheme.php` ;
>
> `/lang/en/` Este subdiretório contém os arquivos de idioma, neste caso
>   Inglês;
>
> `/lang/en/theme_cleantheme.php` - Este arquivo contém todas as strings
>   de idioma para o seu tema. (*Contém alguns elementos que necessitam de
>   mudar o nome, bem como o próprio nome*);
>
> `/layout/` - Esta pasta contém todos os arquivos de layout para este
>   tema;
>
> `/layout/columns1.php` - Arquivo de layout para um layout de coluna
>   (*apenas o conteúdo*);
>
> `/layout/columns2.php` - Arquivo de layout para um layout de duas
>   colunas (*side-pré e conteúdo*);
>
> `/layout/columns3.php` - Arquivo de layout para um layout de três
>   colunas (*side-pre, conteúdo e side-post*) e na primeira página;
>
> `/layout/embedded.php` - Arquivo para incorporação de arquivo de
>   layout como como iframe, object, PDFs;
>
> `/layout/maintenance.php` - Arquivo de layout de manutenção que não
>   tem nenhum blocos, links ou chamadas de API com acesso à base de dados
>   ou interação com os caches;
>
> `/layout/secure.php` - Arquivo de layout seguro para 'saferbrowser' e
>   janela segura;
>
> `/style/` - Esta pasta contém todos os arquivos CSS para esse tema;
>
> `/style/custom.css` - Este é o lugar onde toda a CSS configurações é
>   gerado;
>
> `/pix/` - Esta pasta contém uma imagem do tema propriamente dito,
>   nele também constam arquivos como um favicon e todas as imagens usadas
>   no tema.

**- Renomeando os elementos**

Agora precisamos renomear em todos os arquivos o nome 'clean' para o nome do nosso tema que é `cleanthenme`. Então, usando a lista acima como um guia, vamos pesquisar e alterar todas as ocorrências do nome do tema `clean` para `cleantheme`.

Isso inclui o nome do arquivo do `lang/en/theme_clean.php`. Você precisa mudar isso para `theme_cleantheme.php`.

**Instalando nosso tema**
Uma vez que todas as alterações no nome foram feitas, você pode instalar com segurança o tema. Se você já estiver conectado, pressione a tecla `F5` para atualizar o navegador.  Assim o seu site Moodle irá iniciar a instalação apresentando uma tela para '*Verificar Plugins*'. 
Se não, então navegue para `Administração > Notificações`.

Uma vez que seu tema já está instalado com êxito, você pode selecioná-lo e começar a modificá-lo usando a página de configurações personalizadas. Para encontrá-lo, navegue até `Administração> Administração do Site> Aparência> Temas >` e, em seguida, clique em `(Cleantheme)` ou para o nome do tema que você tenha renomeado.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua colaboração, porém não aceitamos apenas links como respostas, pois o link pode ficar off e sua resposta pobre. Se você puder deixar o código, você estará ajudando muitos outros usuário que tenham a mesma dúvidas.

Comment: Prezado, postagem atualizada com sucesso! Favor reavaliá-lo por gentileza.